# Why constructor of std::set compares the same elements two times?

Tags: c++, std, c++20

Let's consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Obj {
  int x;
  int operator<=> (const Obj& obj) const {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " " << *this << " " << obj << std::endl;
    return x - obj.x;
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Obj& obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Obj& obj) {
  return os << "{ x: " << obj.x << " }";
}

int main() {
  std::set<Obj> st2{{1}, {2}};
  return 0;
}
```

It would yield two rows:

```
operator<=> { x: 1 } { x: 2 }
operator<=> { x: 2 } { x: 1 }
```

At this moment I wonder why it performs two comparisons.

UPD: `g++-10` version: `10.2.0`

Comment: You'd need to state your tool-chain/standard library implementation. [Some do just one comparison](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mm3RqmNnxHSZkz3d).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Strange. The same configuration gives one comparison on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bq4ssP7dWCobb23v) and two comparisons on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5f6avs). I wonder what is missing for the optimization.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen - ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ . There's plenty of things each site's backend can do differently. I thought the OP would like to pin point the reason, but it seems like they were after a more general explanation of why it's possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, if there were more detailed explanation of that phenomenon, I would appreciate it. I mean why it is sometimes optimized and sometimes - not.

Comment: @dronte7 - It's not that it's optimized or not. It's that sometimes we short-circuit and sometimes we don't. It's ultimately due to the order in which the initializer list is processed. [For instance, swapping the elements to `{2}, {1}`).](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gc79WLvV5Oe6mY7G).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably test them for equality. If you look at `std::set`'s template parameters, you can see that it only requires a `less` function to be provided. So how can we test two elements for equality given that we have only `<`? Compare twice. If `!less(a, b) && !less(b, a)`, then `a == b`.

Comment: That works. If you have a full order. Some types only have a partial order though.

Comment: `If !less(a, b) && !less(b, a)`, then they are considered *equivalent* not equal. `std::map` works on equivalence.